# Place get, set for property on one line in Rider

Tags: c#, .net, rider, editorconfig

When I declare a property Rider automatically wraps get and set like this(after typing ';'):

```
private ProductUnit Unit
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

So how do I configure settings to avoid this wrapping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

quick tip for Rider users

for modifying specific code you can select your code

and enter the configure window

[image]

this window will show you, the settings that affect this selected code block

the specific line that you are looking for is the one marked with red:

`Place auto property declaration on single line`

[image]